# No puedo actualizar ni eliminar 2 de mis CORS en mi IIS

Tags: iis, cors, headers, windows-server-2016

Tengo algunos problemas con los que espero que podais ayudarme.

Tengo 2 servidores web 2016, con IIS 10. Y he creado una serie de CORS en estos servidores web (Editor de configuración, system.webserver/httpprotocol y customHeaders). En resumen, he podido crear estas cabeceras de seguridad y he podido eliminarlas, excepto en uno de los servidores web, donde no he podido eliminar 2 de ellas (X-Frame-Options y Strict-Transport-Security). Aparecen como bloqueadas o sombreados o algo así.

Me esta volviendo loco este problema. No me parece logico que solo pase en uno de los 2 servidores y realmente necesito actualizar estas Security Headers. Podeis echarme una mano por favor?

Muchas gracias